# binary search recursive function not working

Tags: python, search, binary

getting "a" as "none" everytime..i am incrementing the value of c if the element(i.e key ) is present in the list  and then returning it. but idk why am i getting none as the answer. please note: the list is already sorted

```
list=[1,2,2,4,6,7,8,8,9]

def binarysearch(list,key,s,e,c):

    if(s<=e):
        mid=int((s+e)/2)
        if (key<list[mid]):
            binarysearch(list,key,s,mid,c)
        elif list[mid]==key:
            c=c+1
            return c
        else:
            binarysearch(list,key,mid+1,e,c)
    else:
        return c

key=2

a=binarysearch(list,key,0,len(list)-1,0)

print(a)
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `c`?

Comment: Have you tried with a shorter list?

Comment: @dmg c is a counter which is incremented if the key is found in the list ,,so in this case c should have the value 1 according to me ,but i am getting none ,,

Answer (score 0):

You must always return the result of your recursion:

```
return binarysearch(list,key,s,mid,c)
```

and

```
return binarysearch(list,key,mid+1,e,c)
```

No doubt this is homework, but just in case you actually need this for real the functionality is provided in the stdlib [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you have a function and dont tell them to return something, in this case:

```
if (key<list[mid]):
    binarysearch(list,key,s,mid,c)
```

and

```
else:
    binarysearch(list,key,mid+1,e,c)
```

you will get none type back

Answer (score 0):

Actually you forgot to return the result of each function call.
You can simply add **return** statement in your code or else here is my code.

```
def binarysearch(l, low, high, key):
  while True:
    if low > high:
      return -1
    mid = (low + high) / 2
    if l[mid] == key:
      return mid
    if l[mid] > key:
      high = mid - 1
    else:
      low = mid + 1
    return binarysearch(l, low, high, key)
```